# All maven modules and submodules are shown in the root tree list

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

This is a IDE related question to Eclipse. I'm using version: Luna Release (4.4.0) with the integrated support for maven. I'm wondering if it's possible to have some more structure in the Package Explorer of Eclipse.

Lets say I have to following maven setup:

```
+ Parent
| + Module 1
| | + Domain
| | + Infra
| | + DomainImpl
| + Module 2
| | + Domain
| | + Infra
| | + DomainImpl
```

This is a valid maven structure. However eclipse will show every project/module in the package explorer:

```
+ Parent
+ Module 1
+ Domain
+ Infra
+ DomainImpl
+ Module 2
+ Domain
+ Infra
+ DomainImpl
```

And of course this is not valid, since some projects are "duplicated". See the following picture:

[image]

Is there any way to have Eclipse correctly order his modules correctly? Because they're on my filesystem:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you import a maven project you can select to change the naming templates.
[image] so you can solve the problem duplicate artifact names in your projects.

Comment: Same goes for when you create new maven modules. Superb, thanks!